# React, having trouble utilizing my config correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some json config I use to define some meta data in a survey app. I've noticed some odd behavior, but I am new to React so I may be missing something obvious.

I have some code like this:

```
const config = require('../../config.json');

/**
  * The input group determines the inputs required from the given frame from the config and renders them.
  */
export class InputGroup extends Component {
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.inputsConfig = config.path[this.props.path].step[this.props.step].inputs;
       }

       componentWillReceiveProps(props){
           console.log(props)
       }

      render() {
        console.log(this.inputsConfig)
```

It correctly gets its props from its parent component, however, the value of inputsConfig never changes to reflect the new props. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider accessing the input props that are passed via the constructor directly, rather than via `this.props`, like this :
`this.inputsConfig = config.path[props.path].step[props.step].inputs;`

Comment: It turns out i'm just and idiot and my JSON had a nesting issue, one frames mapping of inputs was wrong (it was a sibling rather than a child of the "step"), causing the variable to return undefined.

Comment: The constructor is only called once when the component is created.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that was also contributing to the problem, I was thinking of it like a `new object` when a react component would be updated but that was of course not how react works. Thanks for noting it.

Comment: @edh4131 It's exactly like `new MyClass()` in other languages, like Java and C++.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a number of factors, such as the format of the data in your config file, etc.

Perhaps you could take a more functional approach to accessing external configuration in your component, by revising your component's implementation in the following way:

```
const config = require('../../config.json');

export class InputGroup extends Component {

   /*
   Define a local method in your component to extract the 
   configuration, if required props have been supplied and are 
   available on this InputGroup component 
   */
   getInputConfig() {

     const { path, step } = this.props

     // If path and step props have been provided, then retrieve 
     // configuration from config accordingly
     if(path && step) {
        return config.path[path].step[step].inputs;
     }
     else {
        return {}
     }
   }

  render() {
    // Get the configuration for this component by calling the
    // method defined above
    console.log(this.getInputConfig())

    // Return components view 
    return (<div> 
        <p>Your component configuration:</p>
        <p>{{ JSON.stringify(this.getInputConfig()) }}</p> 
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Also, be sure to remember to return some JSX/markup in your render method, in case that's something you forgot to do.

Comment: It was a JSON problem, though I agree that having a get method is probably better than crawling the config in the constructor, since it will make it easier to debug. Thanks!